# angular when click on a particular option in a dropdown, need to change options of that particular dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

```
`values = [
  { value: 3432, lable: "Recent" },
  { value: 3442, lable: "Most Popular" },
  { value: 3352, lable: "Rating" }
];
node = [
{name: 'first node', id: 34},
{name: 'second node', id: 35},
{name: 'third node', id: 36},
{name: 'fourth node', id: 37}
];
valuesDisabled = [
  { value: 3432, lable: "Recent" , disabled: true},
  { value: 3442, lable: "Most Popular", disabled: false },
  { value: -3352, lable: "Rating", disabled: false }
];`

` <p *ngFor="let node of nodes">
<select>
  <p-multiSelect [options]="values"   
     [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="selectedRiskItems[node?.id]"
                id="pickListForscopeReviewersList" appendTo="body" 
  </option>
</select>
</p>`
```

`
on click of -3352 option i want to change options array from values to valuesDisabled only for that particular node not for all nodes, when i am trying to change options for one particular

dropdown, it is effecting all dropdowns under all nodes

i tried to add a disable property to  node objects array and if node.disabled true  i am changing
the options to valuesDisabled example is:-`

```
`<p *ngFor="let node of nodes">
 <p-multiSelect [options]="node.disabled ? values : valuesDisabled"   
     [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="selectedRiskItems[node?.id]"
                id="pickListForscopeReviewersList" appendTo="body" 
  </option>
</p>`
```

> Still getting all dropdowns effected,, but i want only particular
> dropdown need to change options
>
> tried another way as following

```
     node = [
    {name: 'first node', id: 34, values:[{value:1 , lable: 'one', disabled: false},{value:2 , lable: 'two', disabled: false},{value: 3, lable: 'three', disabled: false},]},
    {name: 'second node', id: 35},
    {name: 'third node', id: 36},
    {name: 'fourth node', id: 37}
    ];                                                                                                                                              
      <p *ngFor="let node of nodes">
    <select>
      <p-multiSelect [options]="node.values"   
         [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="selectedRiskItems[node?.id]"
                    id="pickListForscopeReviewersList" appendTo="body" 
      </option>
    </select>
    </p>
```

Comment: i tried to add ` <p *ngFor="let node of nodes">
<select>
  <p-multiSelect [options]="values"   
     [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="selectedRiskItems[node?.id]"
                id="pickListForscopeReviewersList" appendTo="body" 
  </option>
</select>
</p>`